# Synchronization in Windows C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, mutex, condition-variable

I need to implement the following system: 1 writer and 3 readers in mutual-exclusion, but the 3 readers could read in the same time. The writer writes on a shared variable called dato a random number, the readers must print it to the console. The output expected is: 
I wrote: 7; I read: 7 ; I read: 7 ; I read: 7
I wrote: 1; I read: 1 ; I read: 1 ; I read: 1
I wrote: 9; I read: 9 ; I read: 9 ; I read: 9

I used two unique_lock on the mutex m, and two condition_variables: cv1 for the readers (they can read only if writer already wrote) and cv2 for the writer (it could write just if all readers have read).

In order to guarantee parallel read, after the wait I unlocked, and I take the lock after the cout instruction. I think that writer could not take the lock because when they're reading, he is on the wait, and the condition opDone == 3 isn't valid.

Instead, the output is: 
I wrote: 1
I read: 1
I read: I read: 1
I read: 1
I read: 1
1

This is the code:

```
// nreader1writer.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"

condition_variable cv1, cv2;
mutex m;
volatile atomic_int opDone = 0;
volatile atomic_bool iWrote = false;
volatile atomic_bool flag = false;

volatile atomic_int dato;

void writer();
void reader();

int _tmain()
{
    thread t1(reader);
    thread t2(reader);
    thread t3(reader);
    thread t4(writer);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
    return 0;
}

void writer() {
    unique_lock <mutex> ulw (m, defer_lock);
    while (opDone.load() != 3); //In this way, writer starts just when all readers are already waiting 
    ulw.lock();
    opDone.store(0);
    iWrote.store(false);

    while (1) { 
        dato.store( (int) rand()%10);
        cout << "I wrote: " << dato.load() << endl;
        iWrote.store(true);
        cv1.notify_all();
        cv2.wait(ulw, []() {
            return (opDone.load() == 3);
        });
        opDone.store(0);
        iWrote.store(false);
    }
}

void reader() {
    unique_lock <mutex> ulr (m, defer_lock);
    ulr.lock();
    opDone.fetch_add(1);

    while (1) {
        cv1.wait(ulr, []() {
            return (iWrote.load() == true && opDone.load() < 3);
        });
        ulr.unlock();
        cout << "I read: " << dato << endl;
        ulr.lock();
        opDone.fetch_add(1);
        cv2.notify_one();
    }
}
```

The code perfectly run if I don't unlock( ) before read, but in this way the reading operation are not parallel.. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the initialization of your atomic variables. Clang for instance brings up a warning.

```
volatile atomic_int opDone = 0;
// error: copying variable of type 'atomic_int' (aka '__atomic_base') invokes deleted constructor
```

The working draft (current N4527) says the following in §8.5.15.

> **The initialization that occurs in the = form of a**
>   **brace-or-equal-initializer** or condition (6.4), as well as in argument
>   passing, function return, throwing an exception (15.1), handling an
>   exception (15.3), and aggregate member initialization (8.5.1), **is
>   called copy-initialization**. [ Note: Copy-initialization may invoke a
>   move (12.8). — end note ]

The reason is you can't copy atomics. All loads and stores must happen with an explicit call. A fix to the following way should fix the issue:

```
static atomic_int opDone(0);
```